# Mongoengine: How to setup a reference to another model with just its id and not the entire embedded json?

Tags: mongodb, django-rest-framework, mongoengine

I am trying to setup my application that uses mongodb as its backend with mongoengine on top of it. Also trying to expose it as a REST API using DRF. I guess I have a very straight forward question here as I am a novice here - How to setup a ReferenceField in a mongoengine model that when exposed via DRF gets only referenced by its ID and not as an entire embedded object?

Following is my simple setup:

models.py -

```
connect('displent-dev')

class PhotoFull(Document):
    path = StringField()
    title = StringField()
    owner = ReferenceField('UserFull')
    location = StringField()
    date_taken = DateTimeField()
    tags = ListField(StringField())
    focal_length = IntField()


class UserFull(Document):
    first_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    last_name = StringField(max_length=50)
    profile_pic = StringField()
    member_since = DateTimeField()
    membership = StringField()
    theme_pic = StringField()
    photos = ListField(ReferenceField(PhotoFull, reverse_delete_rule=CASCADE))
```

serializers.py:

```
class PhotoFullSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoFull
        exclude = ()

class UserFullSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserFull
        exclude = ()
```

Now when I go to the url - localhost:3223/api/photos (corresponding urls are put in place), I get the complete embedding of related models instead of just their ids:

```
[
    {
        "id": "5446ba4cbc8ae30728b87b23", 
        "path": "media/pic3.jpeg", 
        "title": "Walk in the field", 
        "owner": {
            "profile_pic": "media/profilePic.jpg", 
            "first_name": "Dave", 
            "last_name": "Gordon", 
            "member_since": "2014-01-03T00:00:00", 
            "photos": [
                {
                    "date_taken": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "title": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "tags": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "location": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "focal_length": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "owner": "5441b6b2bc8ae304d4e6c10e", 
                    "path": "Max recursion depth exceeded", 
                    "id": "Max recursion depth exceeded"
                }
            ], 
            "membership": "Silver", 
            "theme_pic": "media/profilePic.jpg", 
            "id": "5441b6b2bc8ae304d4e6c10e"
        }, 
        "location": "Tulip Fields", 
        "date_taken": "2014-09-24T00:00:00", 
        "tags": [
            "Tulips", 
            "Angel", 
            "Sunset"
        ], 
        "focal_length": 90
    },
```

]

The reverse call of `/api/users/` does not yield photos as an array of `objectIds`. I found this from the DRF docs(In UserFullSerializer):

```
photos = serializers.SlugRelatedField(many=True, read_only=True, slug_field="id")
```

When I do this, I get the error that ObjectId("..") is not JSON serializable. It works well when

```
slug_field="title"
```

Any help is really appreciated. This thing has again stalled my front end dev.

Comment: @Kevin Brown. I am sure I am again missing something here. SOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure how the objects are being returned, but you can most likely do this by overriding the `owner` field on the `PhotoSerializer` class.

```
class PhotoFullSerializer(MongoEngineModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.CharField(source="owner.id", read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = PhotoFull
        exclude = ()
```

This should only return the `id` of the `owner` object instead of the entire object.

Comment: Huh. That was a simple solution. Worked as a charm. Never came across this in mongoengine docs. You have no idea how this little thing just unlocked a ton of problems like a domino effect :) Thanks a ton!

Comment: This is a feature of Django REST Framework, where the fields can only return specific parts of the object (such as the `id`). Glad to know it works though. :)

Comment: Great answer. However, how to make it writable? I mean, using this serializer to update reference field with string input?